# Installed SVN -- Possible to create a repository from a directory that already exists

Tags: svn, repository

I have been reading a lot about SVN and am slightly confused.  Mostly because of the inconsistency in semantics used.  Some will call a directory a repo (even though it hasn't been created as one yet) etc.  So I decided I would ask my question as plainly as I can as to not cause any confusion.

What I have done:

I have installed SVN and created an empty repository in `/snv` directory called `dts_staging`.  Now I was under the impression that I could link this `repository` (as I understand it) to a directory that **already exists**.  However my attempts have failed.

The directory that exists is `/var/www/Staging/public_html`.  This is a directory that is full of our websites staging files.  How to I link/sync/combine etc (Not sure the right word to use here) my working directory `var/www/Staging/public_html` with the created repository `/svn/dts_staging`?  Would it be easier to **create** a repo using the `/var/www...` directory?  If so, how is that done?  Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the repository currently empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot simply merge them together. SVN stores the files in so-called "databases" that don't appear to be like the structure of your website.

In order to import it, you have to "commit" the files into SVN. Here is a rough guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409372/committing-the-code-on-subversion-first-time

The actual instructions vary based on what you use for an SVN client. But in any case, it has to be committed.

Comment: Could I do this locally on the server --> `CO` and `COMMIT` to make things faster rather than trying to move 26GB over the network?  I am on Ubuntu 12.10 with Subversion installed.

Comment: If the server your SVN repo is on is the same as the server with the data on it, yes.